# Appropriate usage of TestPropertyValues in Spring Boot Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I came across `TestPropertyValues`, which is briefly mentioned in the Spring Boot docs here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-boot-features.adoc#testpropertyvalues

It's also mentioned in the Migration Guide here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#environmenttestutils

Both examples show an `environment` variable to apply the properties to, but there's no other documentation that I could find.

In my tests the property setting comes too late to affect the property injection (via `@Value`) for a Spring Bean. In other words, I have a constructor like this:

```
  public PhoneNumberAuthorizer(@Value("${KNOWN_PHONE_NUMBER}") String knownRawPhoneNumber) {
    this.knownRawPhoneNumber = knownRawPhoneNumber;
  }
```

Since the above constructor is called before the test code has a chance to run, there's no way change the property via `TestPropertyValues` in the test before it's used in the constructor.

I understand that I can use the `properties` parameter for `@SpringBootTest`, which updates the environment before beans get created, so what's the appropriate usage of `TestPropertyValues`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TestPropertyValues` isn't really designed with `@SpringBootTest` in mind. It's much more useful when you are writing tests that manually create an `ApplicationContext`. If you really want to use it with `@SpringBootTest`, it should be possible to via an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = PropertyTest.MyPropertyInitializer.class)
public class PropertyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThat(this.context.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo")).isEqualTo("bar");
    }

    static class MyPropertyInitializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of("foo=bar").applyTo(applicationContext);
        }

    }

}
```

Spring Boot's own test make use of `TestPropertyValues` quite a bit. For example, `applyToSystemProperties` is very useful when you need to set system properties and you don't want them to be accidentally left after the test finishes (See [EnvironmentEndpointTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ddfdc481612d2d7a662e7236b2831661541f344e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/env/EnvironmentEndpointTests.java#L96) for an example of that). If you search the codebase you'll find quite a few other examples of the kinds of ways it usually gets used.

Comment: that's an awesome example! Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for...! If users are looking for testing the Properties class itself, make sure to define `classes = MyProperties.class` in the params list of `@ContextConfiguration`...